# Remove class and styling of h1 with simple_html_dom results

Tags: php, html, css, simple-html-dom

Following is my code:

```
$html = $_GET['html'];
$dom = file_get_html($html);
$h1 = $dom->find('h1');
echo $h1[0];
```

It returns the H1 text, but along with the class its originally associated with. Like:

```
<h1 class="postpageheading">the returned text </h1>
```

I want only the text, without even the  tag.

How do i do this ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
echo $h1[0]->plaintext;
```

From your `file_get_html` method it looks like you're using the PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser.

If you look at their Quick Start here:

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Click on the tab "Extract contents from HTML" and it shows how to use this `plaintext` to get the contents without tags.

Comment: Thank you master for your quick reply. I am unable to accept the answer as i have to wait for 9 minutes, which i will do. Thank you for educating me  and providing the resource. You Rock !!

Answer (score 1):

you can run a regex over your result like:

```
$result = preg_replace("/[^A-Z]+/", "", $string);
```

or

`strip_tags` as described here: http://php.net/strip_tags

Comment: thanks @noa-dev. I thought of this but was wondering if there is something within simplehtmldom.. thanks.